# How do I get an "a" link to perform a label's "for" function?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, label

I have a pop-up form that appears when a user clicks "Launch Lightbox" in `<label for="lightbox-demo">Launch Lightbox</label>` I need to somehow integrate this `for="lightbox-demo"` into my navigation bar, as a clickable list item.

Here is the code for the navigation bar:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
   <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="current"><a href="#benefits">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#aboutus">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

I need the "Contact" link above to perform the same function as this code:

```
<label for="lightbox-demo">Launch Lightbox</label>
```

This code is associated with the following lightbox/form code:

```
 <aside class="lightbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="state" id="lightbox-demo" />
      <article class="content">

<main class="main">
   <a href="#" id="closer" class="closest"><img src="img/x.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window"  alt="Close Contact Window" /></a>
    <form method="post" action="submit.php" id="contactform" class="signin">
      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />
      <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" required pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" required title="Whoops! Invalid email" aria-required="true"/>
           <textarea name="message" id="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment" required minlength="15" required title="Must be at least 15 characters"></textarea>
            <button id="flybutton">
                <p>Submit </p>
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path id="paper-plane-icon" d="M48z"></path>
                </svg>
            </button>
  </form> 
</main>
    </article>
      <label class="backdrop" for="lightbox-demo"></label>
 </aside>
```

Should be a simple fix but I'm stuck. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using a lightbox library? How does your label open the lightbox?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just wrap the label with the a

```
<label for="lightbox-demo"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></label>
```

---

Otherwise you can also have a click handler

```
<a href="#contact" id="launch-contact">Contact</a>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#launch-contact').click(function () {
        $('#lightbox-demo').prop('checked', true);
    })
})
```

Comment: Ahhh, stupid me. Works perfectly. Thanks for your time. I'll accept your answer once I'm able (7 mins)

Comment: "Why can't you just wrap the label with the a" Because it's not valid to have a label in an a, for the same reason you can't have a button in an a, or an a in another a.

Comment: A label is semantically inappropriate here. Having a click handler on the a element makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this functionality using a click event handler.  Give the label an id so that you can select it using jQuery.

```
<label id="labelForLightbox-demo" class="backdrop" for="lightbox-demo"></label>
```

Add an id on the link so it can also be selected.

```
<a id="contactNavLink" href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

Create a click event handler for the a link to prevent the default action and instead fire the click event on the label.

```
$('#contactNavLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#labelForLightbox-demo').click();
});
```